# how to use a value from sql result as table name for its sub query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my application I want use dynamic table name.

In my application I have two queries.

```
1) SELECT `table_name` FROM `data_tables` WHERE `table_id`="1"
```

From this query I get a table name and I am saving it in a variable; for e.g: $tab

I have another query:

```
2) SELECT * FROM `'.$tab.'`;
```

I want to know is there anyway to club these queries? Is it a good practice?

My application is currently working fine, but I would like some insight.

Comment: You can do it using a combination of [`PREPARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html) and [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). But it's the MySQL equivalent of `eval()` so no, I wouldn't call it good practice

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(max)
SELECT @Name =`table_name` FROM `data_tables` WHERE `table_id`="1"
SELECT * FROM `@Name`
```